# Accessing TPUs in the ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'd like to train my TensorFlow model on a TPU by setting `--scaled-tier` to `basic-tpu`. This is listed as an option in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/submit/training), but there's no mention of TPUs in the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/pricing). Is there any way to find out how much it costs to use TPUs for training?

Comment: Currently, you have to get into the alpha. Talk to your GCP account rep.

Comment: I'm writing a book called TensorFlow for Dummies. Is there any way I can get into the alpha program? I don't have a GCP rep, but I promise to write wonderful things...

Answer (score 0):

There is a signup form linked at the top of the [Cloud TPU page](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/). You can sign up for the alpha there, and also opt in to receive updates on Cloud TPUs.